# How to remove the date from the week view in react big calendar?

Tags: react-big-calendar

[image: 1]

I want to hide the dates from the week view, currently it is 29 Sun, 30 Mon ...  I want it in this way: Sun, Mon, Tue...

Answer (score 0):

In react-big-calendar we have components prop to customise the calendar. In that, header prop is used to customise the header of the calendar.
To implement your need you can refer the below code.

```
const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
<Calendar localizer={momentLocalizer(moment)} components={{
  header: ({date}) => <span>{days[moment(date).day()]}</span>,
}} />
```